# I want to code TicTacToe without using socket.io

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, express

I want to create a TicTacToe game using Express.js/Javascript/HTTP Requests. I don't care for a realtime 'game' application. However, I am hearing that this isn't possible and you have to use web sockets.

This game should be only available on my client and it isn't multi-client.

I can only find vanilla-js or socket.io w/express tutorials on the internet. There are none with express only.

My ex-framework is Ruby On Rails and I am starting to see how easy it was to create applications using this.

What advice would you give me if I wanted to create this game mentioned the title?

Thanks

Comment: `However, I am hearing that this isn't possible and you have to use web sockets.`  Were are you hearing this, as that's totally incorrect.  HTTP only is certainly possible.

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought, I was asking on the room 'node' on Reddit. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: When you say your game is not multi-client, are your saying it's a take a turn on a simple webpage?.. If that's the case it can all be done Javascript, even here creating a working snippet would work.

Comment: I'm confused. If it's single-player, what do you need extra HTTP requests for? The state of the game can be completely maintained and interacted with on the client with plain JS. If you want the server to maintain the state, I guess you could do that, too, but it's extra unnecessary work. You'd just have every player click send a request to the server with the cell number they clicked, then the server uses that to calculate the new state of the board and sends the state back in its JSON response.

Comment: Yeah, the whole point is that I want to create a project with Express.js. I want to test myself.